# java.io.EOFException Jackson Processor

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, jackson

I am using Spring MVC with the Jackson Processor. When a JSON request is sent to the server as a POST request, the @RequestBody is being deserialized into the object that I need. The problem comes when the GET request is sent, it actually displays Http 500 Internal Server error. The exception that is thrown is:

```
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input 
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2022) 
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:1974) 
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1331) 
org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal  (MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:135) 
org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:154) 
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.readWithMessageConverters(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:633) 
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveRequestBody(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:597) 
 org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments  (HandlerMethodInvoker.java:346) 
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171) 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426) 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414) 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790) 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719) 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644) 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

No emtpy strings are sent and the correct JSON is sent to the server. I am not sure why this is happening. Below is my code:

JSP - index.jsp

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html"%>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {  
$('#myForm').submit(function() { 
    var form = $( this ), 
        url = form.attr('action'), 
        userId = form.find('input[name="userId"]').val(),
        dat = JSON.stringify({ "userId" : userId }); 

    $.ajax({ 
        url : url, 
        type : "GET", 
        traditional : true, 
        contentType : "application/json", 
        dataType : "json", 
        data : dat, 
        success : function (response) { 
            alert('success ' + response); 
        }, 
        error : function (response) { 
            alert('error ' + response); 
        }, 
    }); 

    return false; 
   }); 
 }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Application</h2>
<form id="myForm" action="/application/user/find" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="userId" value="user1">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
      </body>
</html>
```

As soon as I change the request type to POST in the JSP and the controller method everything seems to work correctly.

```
package com.web;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user/*")
public class UserController {

@RequestMapping(value = "find", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
public @ResponseBody UserResponse save(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
    UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
                System.out.println("UserId :" + " " + user.getUserId());
    return userResponse;
}
```

beans.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.web"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:annotation-config/>
```

User.java

```
public class User implements Serializable {

private String userId;

public User() {

}

// Getters and setters
}
```

When a GET request is sent the broswer usually displays %%user%%. This is only an example. Does the Jackson processor will still read GET requests?

I don't know where the problem is. I hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the following description on what the data parameter does in jQuey.ajax() does at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/:

Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. ....

So it is appended to the URL and there is no request body. That is a behaviour consistent with the GET semantics, if you want to post data use POST.